# Are official centos-atomic or centos-minimal docker images available?

Tags: docker, centos, redhat

I've seen that Red Hat have their own registry to make available RHEL atomic and minimal docker images.

Are there equivalent CentOS images publically available? I wasn't able to find any on Docker Hub or the Project Atomic downloads.

Answer (score 0):

With [Red Hat Universal Base Image](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introducing-red-hat-universal-base-image) being made available I'd assume that is now their solution to my question since it can be used without a RHEL subscription.

However, it does seem that you need a RHEL subscription to install additional packages onto the base images.